# How to extract numbers from a complex captcha

Tags: python, tesseract, captcha, python-tesseract

I am trying to resolve captcha for the following image

!https://ibb.co/35X723J

I have tried using tessaract

```
data = br.open(captchaurl).read()
b = bytearray(data)
save = open(filename, 'wb')
save.write(data)
save.close()
ctext= pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
```

Comment: I think tesseract cannot read it. It needs a more clear image

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround. You need to clear a bit the image but you wont get a perfect result. Try the following:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2

file = 'sample.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=10, fy=10, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 9)
th, img = cv2.threshold(img, 185, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,8))
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite("sample2.jpg", img)


file = 'sample2.jpg'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(file)
print(''.join(x for x in text if x.isdigit()))
```

Comment: How you decide to take medianBlur, threshold and MORPH_RECT value respectively 9,(185,255) and (4,8)?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

I think using Pytesseract should solve the issue. I tried out your code and it gave me the following result when i gave in the exact cropped captcha image as input into pytesseract:

**Input Image:**

[image: This is the cropped picture from the URL that you specified]

**Output:**

```
print(ctext)
 '436359 oS'
```

I suggest you don't give the full page url as input into pytesseract. Instead give the exact image url as "https://i.ibb.co/RGn9fF5/Jpeg-Image-CS2.jpg" which will take in only the image.

And regarding the extra 'oS' characters in the output, you can do a string manipulation to chop off the characters other than numbers in the output.

```
re.sub("[^0-9]", "", ctext)
```

**Option 2:**

You can also use google's OCR to accomplish this which gives you the exact result without errors. Though I have shown you the web interface of it, google has nice python libraries through which you can accomplish this using python itself. Looks like this:

[image]