# how to extract numbers from captcha image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, captcha

I want to extract numbers from captcha image, so I tried this code from this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58553176/14225905):

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2

file = 'sample.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=10, fy=10, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 9)
th, img = cv2.threshold(img, 185, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,8))
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite("sample2.jpg", img)


file = 'sample2.jpg'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(file)
print(''.join(x for x in text if x.isdigit()))
```

and it worked fine for this image:
[image]
 `outPut: 436359` 
But, when I tried it on this image:
[image]
 It gave me nothing, `outPut:` .
**How can I modify my code to get the numbers as a string from the second image?**

**EDIT:**
I tried [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792105/14225905) and it worked just fine for the image above. but it doesn't recognise numbers like (8,1) in image A, and number (7) in image B
[image: image A] **image A**
 
[image: image B] **image B**

 How to fix that?

Comment: I think you should use this - [How to extract numbers from a complex captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552846/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-complex-captcha)

Comment: @whoamins, it didn't work, as I mentioned I took the code from the answer of that question you pointed out.

Comment: Your code is not recognizing the digits in this particular image, but there are no errors, just choices that don't happen to work for this example, which is a very difficult test case since the letters all skew in different directions. Is your goal to OCR this specific image correctly, or to implement an approach that will correctly recognize as many images as possible? (Nothing will be perfect.)

Comment: @MattL., my goal is to OCR this image correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, getting OCR just right on an image like this has to do with the order and parameters of the transformations. For example, in the following code snippet, I first convert to grayscale, then erode the pixels, then dilate, then erode again. I use threshold to convert to binary (just blacks and whites) and then dilate and erode one more time. This for me produces the correct value of 859917 and should be reproducible.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

file = 'sample2.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(file)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ekernel = np.ones((1,2),np.uint8)
eroded = cv2.erode(gray, ekernel, iterations = 1)
dkernel = np.ones((2,3),np.uint8)
dilated_once = cv2.dilate(eroded, dkernel, iterations = 1)
ekernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
dilated_twice = cv2.erode(dilated_once, ekernel, iterations = 1)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(dilated_twice, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
dkernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
threshed_dilated = cv2.dilate(threshed, dkernel, iterations = 1)
ekernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
threshed_eroded = cv2.erode(threshed_dilated, ekernel, iterations = 1)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(threshed_eroded)
print(''.join(x for x in text if x.isdigit()))
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend, you saved my day. however, the code is not reading numbers with light-yellow colors, how should I process that?

Comment: The most obvious thing is to try changing the first number in the threshold filter function. That controls the cutoff if what is converted to black and white.

Comment: But really it's about tweaking your settings so they work on the maximum number of cases. Nothing will work perfectly for every image.

Comment: @MattL. Can you please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75168470/read-numbers-on-image-using-ocr-python?